# Valid number between two numbers in a textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Allowing only a valid number between x and y to be entered. And display an error message if an invalid number is entered.

I messed around with some if statement and put said x and y numbers in a range, but I don't know how to make that work and display that in lets say a label for example.

I expect the output to be display in a label when a valid number is entered in a text field, when button is pushed. And an error display in a label when an invalid number is enter when the button is pushed.

Comment: Show what you have tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**check if a range contains a value in Swift**

**1. Pattern matching operator ~=**

```
 func validateRange(_ value : Int) {
    if 2..<50 ~= value {
        //in range
    } else {
        // displayLabel.text = "Error message"
    }
}
```

**2. .contains method**

```
func validateRange(_ value : Int) {

    if (2..<50).contains(value) {
       //in range  
    } else {
        // displayLabel.text = "Error message"
    }

}
```

Example :

```
@IBAction func tappedOnOkButton(_ sender: Any) {

   if let value = Int(numberTextField.text) {
      validateRange(value)
   } else {
      // error 
   }
}
```

Comment: on button click you can call the validateRange method with the value which is in numberTextField.

Comment: numberTextField contain a string value so first convert to int and then pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with the help of several ways. following are can be the best way to get into that.

```
func validateNumber() {
     yourLbl.text = checkNumber(startNumber: 10, endNumber: 20, numberToCheck: 11)
}
```

I have created a method which is having several ways to do so... you can keep the best one at your convenient

```
func checkNumber(startNumber: Int, endNumber: Int, numberToCheck: Int) -> String {
    //WITH THE HELP OF `~=` operator
    if startNumber...endNumber ~= numberToCheck {
        return "\(numberToCheck) is within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    } else {
        return "\(numberToCheck) is not within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    }

    //WITH THE HELP OF .contains mathod
    if (startNumber...endNumber).contains(numberToCheck) {
        return "\(numberToCheck) is within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    } else {
        return "\(numberToCheck) is not within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    }

    //WITH THE HELP OF switch statement
    switch numberToCheck {
    case startNumber...endNumber:
        return "\(numberToCheck) is within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    default:
        return "\(numberToCheck) is not within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    }

    //WITH THE HELP OF if statement
    if case startNumber...endNumber = numberToCheck {
        return "\(numberToCheck) is within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    } else {
        return "\(numberToCheck) is not within the range of \(startNumber)-\(endNumber)"
    }
}
```